# Извлечение прошивки UEFI из vmWare

Tags: vmware, uefi

Здравствуйте!

Работаю с vmWare Workstation. Возникла необходимость извлечь прошивку UEFI из файлов vmWare. Обзор GOOGLE дал мало результатов.

Пример с
`vmware-vmx -e <name>`
у меня почему то не отработал. Причину я так же не нашел. Возможно что-то делаю не так.

Есть ли какая-нибудь информация о том, как извлекается прошивка, в каких файлах ее искать и как распознать, что найденное - именно uefi прошивка.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я писал, что пример с `vmware-vmx -e <name>` не отработал с учетом перенаправления вывода. Пример, к слову, был взят с того сайта, что Вы мне прислали. Но все-равно спасибо за ответ!

Прошло немного времени, и я не стоял на месте. Все оказалось очень просто. Через редактор ресурсов открыл `vmware-vmx.exe`. Нашел в `.res/BINARES` файл bios (6006) и 2 файла, содержащие uefi (6020 и 6021).

Comment: Странно, что на Windows команда не отрабатывает, проверял на Mac и Linux все работает. А в Windows 'vmware-vmx.exe' не принимает никакие аргументы, очевидно это баг.

Answer (score 4):

`vmware-vmx -e <name>` у вас отработал, просто результат никуда не записался.

Нужно использовать, после имени модуля, оператор перенаправления вывода команд `>`.

В итоге команда выглядит так:

```
vmware-vmx -e efi64 > vmx-efi64.rom
```

Статья по теме: [ссылка](http://daveparsons.net/blog/2014/01/02/extract-bios-from-vmware/)